# Is the firmware device touchable?

Tags: firmware

We all know that the computer world has both hardware and software. Hardware is touchable and software is not. But apart from those two we have firmware as well. Is firmware touchable (like hardware) or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is firmware touchable?

**Firmware** is made up of hardware **and** software

You can "touch" the hardware part but not the software part.

> In electronic systems and computing, **firmware is the combination of
>   persistent memory and program code and data stored in it**.[1] Typical
>   examples of devices containing firmware are embedded systems (such as
>   traffic lights, consumer appliances, and digital watches), computers,
>   computer peripherals, mobile phones, and digital cameras. The firmware
>   contained in these devices provides the control program for the
>   device.
>
> **Firmware is held in non-volatile memory devices such as ROM, EPROM, or
>   flash memory.** Changing the firmware of a device may rarely or never be
>   done during its economic lifetime; some firmware memory devices are
>   permanently installed and cannot be changed after manufacture. Common
>   reasons for updating firmware include fixing bugs or adding features
>   to the device. This may require ROM integrated circuits to be
>   physically replaced, or flash memory to be reprogrammed through a
>   special procedure.[2] Firmware such as the ROM BIOS of a personal
>   computer may contain only elementary basic functions of a device and
>   may only provide services to higher-level software. Firmware such as
>   the program of an embedded system may be the only program that will
>   run on the system and provide all of its functions.

Source [Firmware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firmware)

Comment: WOW. What a great info. Thank you. It was excellent!!! Two votes!